# Необходимо отслеживать прогресс выполнения операции

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, циклы

Дан код:

```
for user in incoming:
        updating_BD_add.updating_DB_add(group_id, group_name, user, 0, len(incoming), access_token, a)
```

вот сама функция:

```
def updating_DB_add(group_id, group_name, user, i, new, access_tokenб a):

    import requests
    import user_age
    import settings
    import mysql.connector

    database = mysql.connector.connect(user=settings.db_login, password=settings.db_password,
                                       host=settings.dp_ip, database=settings.db_name, use_unicode=True,
                                       charset='utf8', collation='utf8_general_ci', autocommit=True)
    cursor = database.cursor()
    a += 1
    member_request_params = (
        ('user_ids', user),
        ('access_token', access_token),
        ('fields',
         'education, verified, relation, timezone, sex, country, city,  bdate, universities, schools, '
         'last_seen, followers_count, occupation, personal,  activities, interests, music, movies, tv, books, '
         'games,'),
        ('version', 5.73))
    print('Осталось добавить: ', a, 'из',  new - a, 'пользователей')
```

В настоящее время ответ от питона примерно такой:

```
Осталось добавить:  1 из 7977 пользователей
Осталось добавить:  1 из 7977 пользователей
Осталось добавить:  1 из 7977 пользователей
Осталось добавить:  1 из 7977 пользователей
Осталось добавить:  1 из 7977 пользователей
Осталось добавить:  1 из 7977 пользователей
Осталось добавить:  1 из 7977 пользователей
Осталось добавить:  1 из 7977 пользователей
Осталось добавить:  1 из 7977 пользователей
```

Необходимо изменить код, чтоб цифры в ответе python менялись

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде опечатка:

`a =+ 1` -> `a += 1`

---

Да и исправление опечатки не поможет, т.к. неправильно используется переменная.

Я бы сделал так:

```
for i, user in enumerate(incoming, 1):
    updating_DB_add(group_id, group_name, user, i, len(incoming), access_token)
```

И в `updating_DB_add`:

```
def updating_DB_add(group_id, group_name, user, i, max_number, access_token):
    ...
    print('Осталось добавить: {} из {} пользователей'.format(i, max_number))
```

Comment: все хорошо, но тогда получается вот такая ошибка: for i, user in enumerate(1, current_users):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov вы неправильно используете enumerate, читайте текст ответа внимательнее